# PHP how to fetch all data from table and put it accordingly in a div

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

i got alot of tables in my database, and i have specific buttons for each of the table, so when i click on one of the buttons it should display the table rows and columns in a div but it does not display properly for e.g

Note: every table has different number columns and different number rows

[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSuSH.png)
[This is what i want, for each of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U79BJ.png)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ghousn.$table";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
           echo" <table >";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){  
            foreach($row as $key => $val){   
               echo "<tr>";
            echo"<th>$key</th> 
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>$val</td>


      </tr>";
        }
    }
        echo "</table>";


    }
```

Comment: "ghousn" is the name of my database

Comment: why are you using `foreach loop` when you can loop using `while loop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM FROM ghousn.$table";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
echo" <table border='1' >";

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){  
 echo "<tr>";
     foreach($row as $key => $val){   
       echo"<th>$key</th> ";        
     }
  echo "</tr>";
      echo"<tr>";
     foreach($row as $key => $val){   
       echo "<td>$val</td>";        
     }
     echo "</tr>";
 }

echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ghousn.$table";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
echo" <table >";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){  
echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $key => $val){   
      echo"<th>$key</th> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>$val</td>";

    }
  echo "</tr>"
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: it is giving almost the same results